# PouchDB: update document with modified object

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I use Pouchdb to create a database from user data and I would like to update a document with a modified object. For example, I have this initial object:

```
var doc = {
    "_id": "test",
    "trial": 0,
    "results": [11, 22, 33]
};
```

Then I modify it:

```
doc.results[doc.results.length] = 44;
```

I would like to replace the old doc with the new. I tried these steps:

**1/ Initialize PouchDB and the document**

```
var db = new PouchDB('test');
var doc = {
    "_id": "test",
    "trial": 0,
    "results": [11, 22, 33]
};
```

**2/ Put the initial document in the database**

```
db.put(doc);
```

**3/ Modify the document**

```
doc.results[doc.results.length] = 44;
```

**4/ Try to update the database with the new doc**

```
db.get('test').then(function(doc) {
      return db.put(doc);
    }).then(function () {
      return db.get('test');
    }).then(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    });
```

But the document in the database is not modified.

**How can I update the doc with the modified object?**

*UPDATE:*

I can't make the update work even with the _rev. As suggested by mauritslamers, I tried to include the _rev in the doc:

```
var db = new PouchDB('test');
var doc = {
    "_id": "test",
    "_rev": 0,
    "trial": 0,
    "results": [11, 22, 33]
};
```

And in the `put` statement with the following:

```
db.get('test').then(function(doc) {
      return db.put(doc, doc._rev);
    }).then(function () {
      return db.get('test');
    }).then(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should be:

```
db.get('test').then(function(doc) {
      return db.put(doc); // <-- no need to include rev as the second argument
    }).then(function () {
      return db.get('test');
    }).then(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this in the first place and can't make it work: the doc is not updated.

Comment: I see another error: you cannot set `_rev` to `0`. You shouldn't be trying to set `_rev` yourself; the database will generate it for you when you insert a document for the first time. If you get stuck I recommend the guides; they have live examples where you can follow along. :) http://pouchdb.com/guides/

Comment: I began to try without any `_rev` (see the first part of the question) but it doesn't work. I followed the guide examples but I only found cases where the update was made in the `get` statement (change in the age of mittens :) and it works) and none where the update concerns the document itself.

Comment: When you `put(doc1)`, you should never use the `doc1` object again, because it will not be decorated with the `_rev` member. You need to `get()` in order to get a new `doc2` object. That's why all the examples require you to `put()` and then `get()`. E.g. this page describes updating a document: http://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to get a little fancy, you can use the response from the `put` to attach the `_rev` yourself, but this is an entirely optional optimization. E.g. here is an example from our tests: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/9c093980d4bc03b19d9dfdb338f656849ee01a6b/tests/integration/test.conflicts.js#L22-L24

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I think I make exactly the same thing as the guide example: see the 4/ of my question, do you find any problem in it? I used `get` then `put` then `get`.

Comment: Hmm, it's really hard to tell what the problem is. It also looks like you aren't adding `.catch(function (err) { console.log(err); })` to your promise chain, meaning your errors will get silently swallowed.

Comment: I added the `.catch` function but I don't receive any error. It seems that the `get` is creating a new `doc2` object only when an update is done on a field of the `doc1`. It doesn't work either when I try to make a fake update like `db.get('test').then(function(doc) {doc.name = doc.name return db.put(doc);`. However it works if I create a second document and make `db.get('test').then(function(doc) {doc.name = doc1.name return db.put(doc);`.

Comment: I find a (dirty) way to update my docs: create another doc and update each field of the old one. I hope there is a nicer way to do that... I think the problem is that `return db.put(doc);` in our code doesn't `put` the global variable `doc` but the parameter of the function, that is to say the old document... Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Just based on your code I would suspect that you didn't include the _rev in the doc, or in the put call. If I remember correctly, PouchDB works like CouchDB and will require a revision number before successfully updating a document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are right about the cause of the problem but I can't make it work. Please have a look to my update.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a scope issue.

You've used the same object name '**doc**' for your modified document (in the outer/global scope) and modified it outside your get/put promise block (which also had a local scope '**doc**' object that took precedence over your modified doc object).

*i.e. You were GETTING your old document and then PUTTING it straight back...thus it didn't appear to change.*

To make it work:

```
var db = new PouchDB('test');
var doc = {
    "_id": "test",
    "trial": 0,
    "results": [11, 22, 33]
};
db.put(doc);   // initial put

db.get('test').then(function(doc) {
      doc.results[doc.results.length] = 44;    // modify it here instead
      return db.put(doc);
}).then(function () {
      return db.get('test');
}).then(function (doc) {
      console.log(doc);
});
```